# Resolution of yield return value in JavaScript generators

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

If I supply a value to the `next` method on a generator, *in addition to* supplying an expression to the right of the `yield` keyword, how is the return value of the `yield` resolved?

```
function* go() {
  console.log(yield 'a');
  console.log(yield 'b');
}

var g = go();
g.next();
g.next('one');
g.next('two');
```

Output:

```
one
two
Object {value: undefined, done: true}
```

In light of the output, it is the value supplied to the next method that is used over the value returned by the expression to the right of `yield`.

Edit: code updated to better reflect my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "resolved"?

Comment: Notice that you can simplify your example to `function* go() { console.log(yield 'a'); }`

Comment: It seems like there is conflict between the values that could be returned by the `yield` - either the value passed as an argument to `next`, or the value returned by the expression to the right of the `yield` keyword. What are the rules for determining which one is "returned" by the yield.

Comment: The value of the right is never returned from the `yield` expression, except it's driven like `g.next(g.next().value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In light of the output, it is the value supplied to the next method that is used over the value returned by the expression to the right of yield.

The value supplied to the `next` method is not "used over" the value to the right of `yield`. The value supplied to `next` *is* what the `yield` expression ultimately evaluates to. Always. The value to the right of the `yield` is what is supplied to the *consumer* of the generator.

It is a two-way communication between the generator and the code consuming the generator.

```js
function* go() {
  console.log(yield 'a'); // 'one'
  console.log(yield 'b'); // 'two'
}

var g = go();
console.log(g.next());      // { value: 'a', done: false }       
console.log(g.next('one')); // { value: 'b', done: false }
console.log(g.next('two')); // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Comment: ***+1*** for pointing out **It is a two-way communication between the generator and the code consuming the generator**. And I guess [the explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) provided by MDN about the `rv` is a bit misleading since "the value of expression" may refer to _the expression to the right of yield_.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to interpret "return value of the yield".

You could mean the value of the expression `yield 'a'`. That has the value `one`, as you can see from your output.

Or you could mean the value passed to `yield`, which is effectively "returned" from the generator's `next` method. Your code snippet doesn't really reveal this. Try:

```
console.log('next1', g.next());
console.log('next2', g.next('one'));
console.log('next3', g.next('two'));
```

That way you can see the values coming out of the generator, which should look something like:

```
"next1", {value: "a", done: false}
"next2", {value: "b", done: false}
"next3", {value: undefined, done: true}
```

One other thing you can do is add an ordinary `return` value at the end of your generator function, and that will be the `value` for `next3`.