# Assigning yield response to variables

Tags: javascript, generator

How to assign value from yield to a variable?

```
function *foo() {
    var x = yield "foo"
    console.log(x);
}

let bar = foo()
bar.next() // returns {value: "foo", done: false}

bar.next() // returns {value: undefined, done: true}
//console.log logs undefined
```

My understanding was that you can assign values to the variables.

I am trying out in google chrome[image: console]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolution of yield return value in JavaScript generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422838/resolution-of-yield-return-value-in-javascript-generators)

Comment: Where are variables assigned outside of generator function? What is expected result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do assign the result value from `yield` to a variable just fine. It's just that it did return `undefined` in your particular usage of the generator. The result of the `yield` expression is the argument that you pass into the `next` invocation, but you didn't pass anything. Try this instead:

```
function* foo() {
    var x = yield "foo";
    console.log(x);
    return "baz";
}

var bar = foo();
bar.next();      // returns {value: "foo", done: false}
bar.next("bar"); // console.log logs "bar"
                 // returns {value: "baz", done: true}
```